# Python Pypotrace installation

Tags: python-3.x

I have followed all steps to install pypotrace in Windows 10.

i am using Python 3.7 Lib.

i have successfully build "./configure; make" & "./autogen.sh; make" but after that when i executed

```
python setup.py build_ext -IC:\Users\Yogesh\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy;C:/src/potrace-1.15/src;C:/src/agg-2.4-LC:/src/potrace-1.15/src/.libs;C:/src/agg-2.4/src
```

it shows me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 70, in <module>
    cython=CYTHONIZE),
  File "setup.py", line 45, in create_ext_obj
    pkg_config_output = subprocess.check_output(args)
  File "C:\Users\Yogesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\Yogesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Yogesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Yogesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please guide me how to install pypotrace

Answer (score 4):

My solution to this problem was to give up and port potrace to pure python.

`pip install potracer`

https://github.com/tatarize/potrace

I implemented the same API as pypotrace so it should be fairly painless.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
pip install pypotrace
```

https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/

Building from source is a PAIN if you're not used to it and pip makes installation so simple.

EDIT

you could try this in a terminal

```
git clone 'https://github.com/flupke/pypotrace'
cd pypotrace
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Have a look at the github page - its not so easy on windows. Get your self on Linux my friend.

Comment: _potrace.c(617): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'potracelib.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: using ubuntu in windows 10 can be installed this library

Comment: If you are talking a virtual machine then yeah sure, or if you can find a docker container with it then you are laughing.

Comment: https://exceptionshub.com/python-pypotrace-potrace-installing-on-windows-windows10.html